# Find all nested img element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to target all nested `img` elements withing varying levels of a container, for example..

```
<div>
    <img>
    <p><img></p>
    <div>
        <p>
            <img>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, I want to filter them by size so i've used `if (imgs.width() > 1080) {}`

I'm using the jQuery `find()` method, but not having any errors, or results. Here's what I've got

```
 var imgs = $(".entry-content").find("img");
  imgs.each(function() {
    if (imgs.width() > 1080) {
    imgs.css({"width": "100%", "height": "auto"});
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use find at all. In jQuery you'll want to use $(this) to target the specific instance of that loop.

```
$('.entry-content img').each(function (i, o) {
  if ($(this).outerWidth() > 1080) {
    $(this).css({"width": "100%", "height":"auto"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Won't that only affect direct descendants of the `.entry-content` container?

Comment: It will affect any image thats contained within `.entry-content`, no matter how deep.